# How to connect android to online database(mysql)

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am new to android development, i want to access the online databse(mysql) through android. how can i do that. please help.

thanks

Comment: Establish socket connection to connect mysql or use php server connection

Comment: This is a bad idea. I would recommend building an API that can be locked down tightly instead.

Comment: I think is better you use webservice, with JSON.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/ Follow this

Comment: A socket connection? Was that serious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomend you to use webservice using JSON. Here is a good example.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

Answer (score 1):

There are lot's of tutorial for that. Just google it. For this you have to crate a intermediate PHP page. Just go through the following tutorial. It will help you.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

Answer (score 1):

you have to create webservice in php  and using JSON parsing ..you have fetch records from those webservices